# Form still submitting without Info even with the required attribute in the code

Tags: html, css, forms

My demo form is submitting even when I don't fill out info but I added the required attribute in the code.

```html
<form class="form" action="#" validate>
   <div>
      <div class="labels">
         <label for="full-name">Full Name</label>
      </div>
      <input
         id="full-name"
         type="text"
         placeholder="John Smith"
         required
         />
   </div>
   <div>
      <div class="labels">
         <label for="email-address">Email Address</label>
      </div>
      <input
         id="email-address"
         type="email"
         placeholder="Johnsmith@example.com"
         required
         />
   </div>
   <div>
      <div class="labels">
         <label for="select">Where did you hear about us? </label>
      </div>
      <select id="select" required>
         <option value="facebook">Facebook</option>
         <option value="google">Google</option>
         <option value="friendsandfamily">Friends and Family</option>
         <option value="youtube">Youtube</option>
         <option value="Podcast">Podcast</option>
      </select>
   </div>
    <button class="btn--form">
              <a href="#" class="btn">Sign Up Now</a>
            </button>
</form>
```

I added the required attribute and tested the form but it still submits without prompting me to fill out all fields before submitting.

Comment: The form shown has no submit button and no action to which it submits.  Can you clarify specifically what isn't working as expected in the code shown and what specific debugging observations you've made?

Comment: I want the form to require users to fill out all fields before submitting. But It's submitting without requiring them to fill out the fields.

Comment: `<button>` elements are not allowed to contain `<a>` element. Start with valid HTML. https://validator.nu/

Comment: The change you've made to the code makes even less sense.  Why do you have a link *inside of* a button?  Are you clicking the link, or are you clicking the button?  What debugging have you done to confirm?  Have you tested this at all since making this change?  Your link has no `href` destination, and your form has no `action` destination, so *neither of them* will "submit the form".

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, if I click the button (taking care to avoid clicking on the invalid link *inside* the button) then the "Please fill in this field" message appears.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you take out the `<a>` tag it works. Also I added `type="submit"`.

```
    <button class="btn--form" type="submit">
              <!-- <a href="#" class="btn"></a> -->
            Sign Up Now
    </button>
```